# Remove battery notifications in Gnome 3.20

Tags: gnome, battery, notification

My battery is dead and it is always %0. I want to disable/remove battery notifications in GNOME which pops up every minute but couldn't manage to do it.

I tried every solution in the internet but none of them worked so far.

I removed `gnome-power-manager`, changed settings in `dconf-editor > org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power`

Still not able to remove/disable `Laptop battery critically low` notification.

Thanks.

Comment: Gnome 3.20 was on Ubuntu 16.10 which is EOL.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?, as if still on 16.10 you are two releases behind and I'd fix that first.

Comment: @guiverc I am on 16.04 i fresh installed ubuntu-gnome version and updated gnome manually

Comment: @guiverc so there is no way to remove notifications without upgrading ubuntu ?

Comment: be patient & wait for a response.  I'm not a gnome user & use workstations...